# Is there any way to turn off autocorrection / set keyboard type on the searchable navigation modifier in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

In SwiftUI you can set a [`searchable` modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/searchable(text:placement:)) on a view in a `NavigationView` to show a search bar. However by default this search bar has autocorrection enabled, plus one might want to modify the keyboard or the auto-capitalization type.

For example, this autocorrection for example resulted in my typing in some text, tapping on a row to open a detail page, then it pops back to the list because it automatically replaced my search query with the autocorrected value.

Apple's example code (which is effectively the same as what I'm doing, minus a `List` with `NavigationLink`s):

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        PrimaryView()
        SecondaryView()
        Text("Select a primary and secondary item")
    }
    .searchable(text: $text)
}
```

The definition/documentation of `searchable` doesn't show any obvious way to do it.

Any way to do this while still taking advantage of the convenience of the `searchable` modifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
NavigationView {
    PrimaryView()
    SecondaryView()
    Text("Select a primary and secondary item")
}
.searchable(text: $text)
.disableAutocorrection(true)    // << here !!
```

Comment: Thank you! Also there's `.autocapitalization(.none)` which can be used in the same spot.

Comment: .autocapitalization(_:) is deprecated. Use textInputAutocapitalization(_:) instead.